# JavaFX Exception in Application constructor java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to have an instance of MainPage in EditPage class, while having an instance of EditPage in MainPage class.
However, I get exception. Why this exception occur? and how to solve this problem?

Here is my application class that has a main method:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import pages.MainPage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {

            data.fileSetUp();
            data.loadMeta();

            mainScene.setAlwaysOnTop(stage);
            mainScene.updateAlwaysOnTop(stage);
            mainScene.setEditAction(stage);

            stage.setScene(mainScene.getScene());
            stage.show();
            stage.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
                try {
                    data.saveMeta();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    DataControl data = new DataControl();

    MainPage mainScene = new MainPage();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is a MainPage class:

```
package pages;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import application.DataControl;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainPage {

    public Scene getScene(){

        arrayReady.add(txtReady1);arrayReady.add(txtReady2);arrayReady.add(txtReady3);arrayReady.add(txtReady4);arrayReady.add(txtReady5);
        for (Text txt:arrayReady){
            txt.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20");
        }

        arrayEdit.add(lEdit1);arrayEdit.add(lEdit2);arrayEdit.add(lEdit3);arrayEdit.add(lEdit4);arrayEdit.add(lEdit5);
        for (Label label:arrayEdit){
            label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20");
        }

        arrayMenu.add(lAlwaysOnTop);arrayMenu.add(lControl);
        for (Label label:arrayMenu){
            label.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 15");
        }

        gridReadyEdit.addColumn(0, txtReady1,txtReady2,txtReady3,txtReady4,txtReady5);
        gridReadyEdit.addColumn(1, lEdit1,lEdit2,lEdit3,lEdit4,lEdit5);
        gridReadyEdit.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridReadyEdit.setHgap(20);
        gridReadyEdit.setMaxSize(300, 0);

        gridMenu.addRow(0, lAlwaysOnTop,lControl);
        gridMenu.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        gridMenu.setHgap(20);
        gridMenu.setMaxSize(300, 0);
        gridMenu.setStyle("-fx-border-color:lightgrey");

        pane.getChildren().addAll(gridReadyEdit,gridMenu,lVersion);
        StackPane.setAlignment(gridMenu, Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        StackPane.setAlignment(lVersion, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

        return scene;
    }

    public void setEditAction(Stage stage){
        arrayEdit.clear();
        arrayEdit.add(lEdit1);arrayEdit.add(lEdit2);arrayEdit.add(lEdit3);arrayEdit.add(lEdit4);arrayEdit.add(lEdit5);
        for (Label label:arrayEdit){
            label.setOnMousePressed(e->{
                stage.setScene(editPage.getScene());
            });
        }
    }

    public void setAlwaysOnTop(Stage stage){
        lAlwaysOnTop.setOnMousePressed(e->{
            if (DataControl.checkAlwaysOnTop == 1){
                DataControl.checkAlwaysOnTop = 0;
                updateAlwaysOnTop(stage);
            } else {
                DataControl.checkAlwaysOnTop = 1;
                updateAlwaysOnTop(stage);
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateAlwaysOnTop(Stage stage){
        if (DataControl.checkAlwaysOnTop == 1){
            lAlwaysOnTop.setText("Always On Top: Yes");
            stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        } else {
            lAlwaysOnTop.setText("Always On Top: No");
            stage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        }
    }

    public GridPane getGridMenu(){return gridMenu;}

    private ArrayList<Text> arrayReady = new ArrayList<Text>();
    private ArrayList<Label> arrayEdit = new ArrayList<Label>();
    private ArrayList<Label> arrayMenu = new ArrayList<Label>();

    private Label lVersion = new Label("Version 1.0");
    private Label lEdit1 = new Label("EDIT");
    private Label lEdit2 = new Label("EDIT");
    private Label lEdit3 = new Label("EDIT");
    private Label lEdit4 = new Label("EDIT");
    private Label lEdit5 = new Label("EDIT");
    private Label lAlwaysOnTop = new Label();
    private Label lControl = new Label("Control Setting");

    private Text txtReady1 = new Text("1. Ready");
    private Text txtReady2 = new Text("2. Ready");
    private Text txtReady3 = new Text("3. Ready");
    private Text txtReady4 = new Text("4. Ready");
    private Text txtReady5 = new Text("5. Ready");

    private GridPane gridMenu = new GridPane();

    private GridPane gridReadyEdit = new GridPane();

    private StackPane pane = new StackPane();

    private Scene scene = new Scene(pane,300,300);

    private EditPage editPage = new EditPage();
}
```

This is an EditPage class:

```
package pages;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class EditPage{

    public Scene getScene(){

        pane.getChildren().addAll();

        return scene;
    }

    private StackPane pane = new StackPane();

    private Scene scene = new Scene(pane,300,300);

    private MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

Lastly, Here is an error messages:

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class application.Main
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/1645995473.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$158(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/2125582483.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/186276003.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1698672883.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/237061348.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/2117255219.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.SelectorPartitioning.match(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.findMatchingStyles(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.createStyleHelper(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.reapplyCss(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_reapplyCSS(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$9.invalidated(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.setRoot(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:115)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
    at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
    at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
Exception running application application.Main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why this exception occur?

The `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` happened because something went wrong (and exception was thrown) while the JavaFX app was launching.

You can find  out what went wrong by examining the stack trace.  In particular, look at the nested exceptions.  In this case, the ultimate "cause" exception is a `StackOverflowError`.

So what caused the `StackOverflowError`?  Well judging from stack frames, there is an "infinite recursion" where:

- a `MainPage` creates an `EditPage`
- an `EditPage` creates a `MainPage`
- a `MainPage` creates an `EditPage`
- an `EditPage` creates a `MainPage`
- and so on *ad infinitum*.

The evidence for this is the repeating pattern of stackframes:

```
at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
at pages.EditPage.<init>(EditPage.java:23)
at pages.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:117)
```

A cursory examination of your code will show you where it is happening.  (Hint: the `<init>` means that it is happening during object construction, and the stack trace even tells you the source code line numbers!)

> and how to solve this problem?

Fix the bug in your code that is leading to the infinite recursion.

Almost certainly ... the `EditPage` should not be creating a `MainPage`.  You probably need to pass a reference to the `MainPage` as an argument to the `EditPage` constructor.