# JavaFx NullpointerException when running jar

Tags: javafx, jar, nullpointerexception, launch

Heho community,
i created a JavaFx application and everythin worked fine, when i run it within eclipse. But when i run the app as jar file i get the following error. A few days ago i had another problem with the controller (which could be solved) and an "hidden" invocationTargetException, which just appears in the console of Eclipse, when having another Error. I couldnt fix this one and i guess the Error occuring when run the jar refers to that. Here´s the link to my old question: [JavaFX Exception in Application constructor java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099462/javafx-exception-in-application-constructor-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetex)

The current Error when running jar:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at application.Main.start(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my Main:

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import application.view.ControllerSpielanleitung;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.DepthTest;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            //anLeitungLaden();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("resources/Layout.fxml"));
            Pane pane = (Pane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hashiwokakero");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);

            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResource("resources/Alien.png").toString()));
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
};
```

and Layout.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<Pane id="root" fx:id="root" prefHeight="839.0" prefWidth="1281.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="application.view.Controller">
    <children>
        <Pane id="pane" fx:id="pane" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="64.0"
            maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
            minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="749.0" prefWidth="1209.0"
            style="-fx-border-radius: 100; -fx-border-width: 100;">
            <children>
                <Button id="newLevelButton" fx:id="newLevelButton" layoutX="363.0"
                    layoutY="303.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleNewLevelButton"
                    prefHeight="66.0" prefWidth="484.0"
                    style="-fx-border-color: #ffd308; -fx-border-radius: 30;" text="Weiter zu Level 2"
                    textFill="#ffd308">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Franklin Gothic Medium Cond" size="40.0" />
                    </font>
                </Button>
                <Button id="hintButton" fx:id="hintButton" layoutX="1042.0"
                    layoutY="685.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleHintButton"
                    prefHeight="41.0" prefWidth="153.0"
                    style="-fx-border-color: #ffd308; -fx-border-radius: 30;" text="Hinweis"
                    textFill="WHITE">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Franklin Gothic Medium Cond" size="26.0" />
                    </font>
                </Button>
            </children>
        </Pane>
        <CheckBox id="checkboxSoundeffect" fx:id="checkboxSoundeffect"
            layoutX="1032.0" layoutY="23.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
            onAction="#handleCheckboxSoundEffect" text="Soundeffekte" textFill="WHITE" />
        <CheckBox id="checkboxMusic" fx:id="checkboxMusic" layoutX="1185.0"
            layoutY="23.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleCheckboxMusic"
            text="Musik" textFill="WHITE" />
        <Label fx:id="labelLevel" layoutX="33.0" layoutY="14.0"
            prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="136.0" text="Level 1" textAlignment="CENTER"
            textFill="WHITE">
            <font>
                <Font name="Franklin Gothic Medium Cond" size="40.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
    </children>
</Pane>
```

Please, does anybody know how to fix it? Im searching for a solution the whole day and slowly getting crazy -.-

EDIT: When trigger an Error an run within Eclipse, this error also occurs:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/bertr/eclipse-workspace/Hashiwokakero2/bin/application/resources/Layout.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Invalid argument to operation ++/--

    at application.view.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:70)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: It's strange that it's reporting "Unknown Source" in the exception; you should be able to build this so that the line numbers are available, which would help you debug it. I would start by checking that the CSS file and image file are included in the jar file, and are in the expected location. The other thing to do, of course, is to put the result of the calls to `getClass().getResource(...)` into variables, and log their values before using them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I checked the image and css file and they are included in the expected location.

Comment: The expected locations being `application/resources/Layout.fxml`, `application/application.css`, and `application/resources/Alien.png`, of course.

Comment: Exactly, they are at that location.

Comment: How are you building this project? The most useful thing you can do is to build it so that you can at least get a line number on the NPE.

Comment: I suppose that the error is not really in the building of the jar. When i intentionally trigger an error (for example invalid syntax in my controller) and then run my project within eclipse i see that error of course and suddenly another one, of wich i think it is actually the same like the one when running the jar. i edit this one in my question

Comment: The error's not necessarily in building the jar. I was asking about that because something in the way you have built it is preventing the JDK from getting all the information you need when the exception occurs. You need a line number in `Main.java`, instead of `"Unknown Source"`, so that you can diagnose the problem. Not really sure what you mean by introducing invalid syntax in the controller: surely that would just generate a compile error, not a runtime error?

Comment: Oh okay i got you wrong. But does my edit make my intention with triggering an error clearer? Then the original error might appear in main(24) in load(). But why? :(

Comment: No. I have no clue what introducing a compile error has to do with anything you are asking about. Of course you get an error loading the FXML if there is a problem with the controller. Don't clutter your question with nonsense.

Comment: Your `start()` method is simple enough that you can analyze it directly. The only possible places you can get a null pointer exception in that method are from `getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm()` or `Main.class.getResource("resources/Alien.png").toString()` : i.e. the only possible things that can be null, that you are dereferencing are `getClass().getResource("application.css")` or `Main.class.getResource("resources/Alien.png")`. So, if you can't figure out how to build this with debug info, put those into variables and log their values at the beginning of `start()`.

Comment: Oh jesus i wasnt thinking clearly. that happens when sitting in front of the screen since over 12h -.- 
The image returns null! Now it works! Thank you very much for your help and especially your patience, James_D!

Comment: @MagdalenaBertram please consider answering your own question with your solution and then marking it as the correct answer. :)